# Prisma connecting explicit many to many relations, vscode's intellisense/compiler doesn't match up syntax described in docs?

Tags: node.js, prisma

Models:

```
model User {
....
  conversations ConversationRelation[] @relation("conversations")
}


model ConversationRelation {
  user           User         @relation("conversations", fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  conversation   Conversation @relation("conversations", fields: [conversationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  conversationId String
  userId         String
  isAdmin        Boolean

  @@id([conversationId, userId])
}

model Conversation {
  id               String                 @id @default(uuid())
  participants     ConversationRelation[] @relation("conversations")
}
```

The [docs here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations) suggest the syntax should be like:

[image]

The create object takes what's relevant for the relation table, not the category table. In my case therefore, I should have the 'isAdmin' property available when creating.

But when trying to define properties in the create object, the only properties that I have available are what's available on the user object + some array methods (???) instead.

What's the right way of doing this?

Example of actual behaviour:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you have explicitly defined the `ConversationRelation` model? If you don't specify this, and instead have `User` and `Conversation` point to each other, Prisma will take care of the "join" model under the hood so you won't have to do anything extra.

Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#relation

If you want to explicitly define this join model, you should not use the same `name` property in `@relation` for each of them (the first argument to `@relation`). I think Prisma is getting confused with there being multiple relations with the same name and different models. I would recommend removing the first argument of `@relation` (since it's not required for your use case.)

Additionally, you don't need the `@relation` attribute on the `User` and `Conversation` model in this situation. So your models would look something like this:

```
model User {
  id                   String                 @id @default(uuid())
  ConversationRelation ConversationRelation[]
}

model ConversationRelation {
  user           User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  conversation   Conversation @relation(fields: [conversationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  conversationId String
  userId         String
  isAdmin        Boolean

  @@id([conversationId, userId])
}

model Conversation {
  id                   String                 @id @default(uuid())
  ConversationRelation ConversationRelation[]
}
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#relation

Comment: Hi, I want to cascade deletes and that required the relations to be explicit, on top of adding that `isAdmin` metadata on top of the relation, not exactly sure why I ended up specifying the relation name, I'll give it a shot and get back to you first thing tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: For these kinds of relationships, you can't specify the referential action behavior on the model which references an array. So you can specify `onDelete` on `ConversationRelation`, but not on `User` or `Conversation`. You only really need to specify the `onDelete` once, though. Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions#caveats